# How to hide url from the tweet body when sharing on twitter through URL?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm sharing a page `url` on twitter using this anchor tag:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"></a>
```

and it works perfectly fine and displays preview of the URL in the tweet but I want to hide the URL present in the tweet body. See the attached image:

[image: hide]

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a tweet, the URL will always be visible. However, as soon as the tweet is posted the URL is hidden automatically and only the preview of the page remains.

I tested this myself, and found this answer on: [reddit.com/r/Twitter/comments](https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitter/comments/6xewtx/posting_a_link_in_a_tweet_with_no_url_showing/)

Comment: Yes as I know it is not possible.

Comment: Yeah I read the same article and it's not possible.

Btw can same `open graph` tags be used for both `Linkedin` & `Facebook` ?